# How to convert a string to DOM and selecting within it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string containing HTML.

I need

- part one: convert the string to DOM element and using jquery to
  selecting all images
- part two: update all image src adding "xxxx/"    before the current
  src value

Any idea how to do it?

```
var resp = '<div><img src="smiley1.gif"></div><div><img src="smiley2.gif"></div><div><img src="smiley3.gif"></div>';

var dom = $(resp).html();
```

the result rendered as html should be:

```
<div><img src="xxxx/smiley.gif"></div><div><img src="xxxx/smiley.gif"></div><div><img src="xxxx/smiley.gif"></div>;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well hope this is what you want.

```
var re = /src=\"/gi;
var str = '<div><img src="smiley.gif"></div><div><img src="smiley.gif"></div><div><img src="smiley.gif"></div>';
var newstr = str.replace(re, "src=\"xxxxxx\/");
alert(newstr);
```

Here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/4L5Q8/

Comment: I understand your point, my problme is every img has different src.. like <div><img src="smiley1.gif"></div><div><img src="smiley2.gif"></div><div><img src="smiley3.gif"></div>

Comment: is /src=\"/gi a regular expression?

Comment: @GibboK ya it is, 'g' all instances, 'i' insensible to case

Comment: Problem with this solution could be if your DOM string contains other elements than images with attribute src. I guess in your specific case it is not an issue

Comment: @A.Wolff As I know i think only `<script>` tag holds the `src` attribute? and `var re = /\<img\ssrc=\"/gi;`, `var newstr = str.replace(re, "<img src=\"xxxxxx\/");` working well :)

Comment: @jogesh_pi you can have video/audio tags too or in worst case, some custom data attribute as data-src. And concerning your edit, thats' suppose src attribute to follow directly the img declarative tag but could be fixed quite easily for sure.

Comment: Thanks guys for commenting, in my case I have only image tags

Answer (score 1):

Could be done like that:

```
var dom = $('<div/>').html(resp).find('img').attr('src', function () {
    return 'xxxx/' + $(this).attr('src')
}).end().html();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gFBLf/)

Answer (score 1):

**Using Jquery:**

```
var resp = '<div><img src="smiley.gif"></div><div><img src="smiley.gif"></div><div><img src="smiley.gif"></div>';

$(resp).appendTo($('body'));
$('img').each(function(){this.src = "xxxxxx" + this.src;})
```